# Laravel 5 - Cron Jobs Windows

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5

I'm new to Cron Jobs, and haven't made anything before. I want to make a cron job that deletes folders older than 15 days. I have a Call Recording System which I store recordings on

```
/public/uploads
```

And inside that are folders with the recording file inside each one of them. I want a task or cron job that will scan these folder let's say every 1:00am and delete all folders that is more than 15days old or 15days prior to the date when the folder is created in the directory. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, you can do that with some php code. Let us know how it went.

Comment: Cron jobs is something you setup on your server / computer. And what it does is just run a script or command on your server. So I suggest you setup a artisan command that will remove the folders, then create a cron job to trigger that artisan command. Check out http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/149/recursively-deleting-a-directory